# looking for #python name module, similar to enchant

Tags: python, string, list

I've recently got an assignment go count the number of WORDS in a sentence. simple enough, right?

you assign the input sentence to a list, you .split() it, and then you .count.

problem is:

a) what if the sentence isn't a sentence? (not ending with a dot)?
easy enough to solve: checking is string[-1][-1]=="." and we're done.

b) this is where things get tricky....

what if a word - isn't a word at all??

examples: djgghjdjgf, 7zark7. blizz-ard, twi@ter etc.

I've found pyenchant to solve most issues...but:

1. it doesn't recognize words which ends with apostrophe (') like Chris' - as a word.  in fact, it doesn't recognize names as words at all....

I can run a double .check: one for pyenchant, but I must do another to see if it's a name..which is a word...

anyone know a similar mudule to pyenchant (which is basically a dictionalry), only with NAMES (if any exists)?

that would be much appreciated.

other solutions are also welcome.

p.s.

the len(s.split()) just can't be right? If I'll right #%#$65477 - that's NOT(!) a word. it's just an item in a list (and I was asked for words, probably real ones).

thanks again.

Comment: Asking for endorsement of modules is off topic. Do not over complicate things. If you need to  count specific words, ask for an exhaustive list of them. There is no "list of names" - John, Jon, Joan, Jobs - wich one is a name? "Jobs said ..." and "Jobs are seldom fun" - where is it used as name and where not? Context matters: "Steve Job is a cool guy. Jobs said ..."  If you need to distinguish between "meaningful word" and "letter garbage" you may need context, semantic or natural language processing capabilities. Btw. sentences may also end on ? or ! beside .

Comment: You may profit from reading [Falsehood programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) - just for the fun of it and to broaden the concept "Name".

Comment: you're right on all accounts.  I think I'll just solve in the regular manner, not looking to do things I lack the ability to do at this point (even if that moduleI I've asked about actually existed). thank you very much for your help.

Comment: after reading your suggested material I have an even better understanding of what you meant.  thank you for saving me the time and effort on a pretty futile mission.  I'll just do it the 'textbook' way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just as #Patrick Artne said, there's no way to distinguish between names with double meanings and variety of reasons.  in a nut shell - what I was asking just can't be done.